# How to remove the spaces before equation in align environment?

Tags: align

```
\begin{align}
    IP:Z =\Max \sum\limits_{j=1}^J  y_j\label{SoC1}\\
    \text{subject to} \notag \\
     \sum\limits_{l=1}^{L_k} x_{klm}=1\qquad k=1,2,...,K, m=1,2,....,M;\label{SoC2} \\
    \sum\limits_{m=1}^M y_{jm}\geq y_j\qquad          j=1,2,..,J,m=1,2,....,M;\label{SoC3}\\
    \sum\limits_{k=1}^K\sum\limits_{l=1}^{L_k}u^j_{kl} x_{klm} \geq h_j y_{jm}\qquad j=1,2,...J, m=1,2,...,M, \notag\\
k=1,2,...,K,\ell=1,2,...,\ell,...,L_k;\label{SoC4}
    \end{align}
```

I am using the following code for a mathematical model. The first two lines of the code are not getting aligned properly and are too far to the right. I tried {flalign}, but it still seems to be in the same place. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't specify any alignment points. Why use `align` in this case?

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `flalign`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  \qquad &  IP:Z  =\max ∑_{j=1}^J  y_j &    & \label{SoC1}\\[-1ex]
  \shortintertext{subject to}
  &  ∑_{l=1}^{L_k} x_{klm} =1, & &  k=1,2,\dots, K, &  m & =1,2,\dots,M; \label{SoC2}\\%
  &   ∑_{m=1}^M y_{jm} \geq y_j ,      & &  j=1,2,\dots, J,  & m & =1,2,\dots,M;\label{SoC3}\\%
  &  ∑_{k=1}^K∑_{l=1}^{L_k}u^j_{kl} x_{klm} \geq h_j y_{jm}, & &  j=1,2,\dots , J,\!  &m&=1,2,\dots,M,\notag \\[-2ex]
  &  &  & k=1,2,\dots,K, & \ell & =1,2,\dots, \ell,\dots,L_k.\label{SoC4}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't know, if this is what you're looking for:

[image: :D]

Source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Fontencoding: 7bit -> 8bit
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
IP:Z = \sum\limits_{j=1}^J  y_j& \label{SoC1}\\
\text{subject to} \notag \\
\sum\limits_{l=1}^{L_k} x_{klm}&=1\qquad
& k=1,2,...,K, m=1,2,....,M;\label{SoC2} \\
\sum\limits_{m=1}^M y_{jm}&\geq y_j\qquad
& j=1,2,..,J,m=1,2,....,M;\label{SoC3}\\
\sum\limits_{k=1}^K\sum\limits_{l=1}^{L_k}u^j_{kl} x_{klm} &\geq h_j y_{jm}\qquad
& j=1,2,...J, m=1,2,...,M, \notag\\
&&k=1,2,...,K,\ell=1,2,...,\ell,...,L_k;\label{SoC4}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

You need to make use of the `&` alignment in an align- environment. Else, latex does not know, what to align how.